# What is the next 3 numbers?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

These numbers are created with a formula.
Guess the formula for increment and calculate at least 3 next numbers of this sequence.

increment is started with two given first $1$s.

> $1,$
>   $1,$
>   $2,$
>   $3,$
>   $11,$
>   $44,$
>   $129,$
>   $557,$
>   $2354,$
>   $7059$

Comment: I just spent ten minutes with my TI-84 and WolframAlpha trying to figure this out. *What sorcery is this?!*

Comment: I'll try it when I can

Comment: I've spent and hour trying to figure this out D:

Comment: @Undo, Happy to know... lol. That was my goal to challenge puzzle solvers ;)

Comment: What operators are allowed ?

Comment: @Seb, the only hint I can give is: nothing more than elementary school

Comment: @warspyking What did you try? :p

Comment: @d'alar Exactly what I just posted!

Comment: The apparent answer is really ugly. Is there a graceful way to come up with the answer to questions like this? It seems like the function is so complicated that you have to guess, use a tool, or apply a predefined algorithm until you get an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll write $S_n$ for the $n$-th term in the sequence. The terms you listed satisfy the recurrence
$$
S_{n+1}=\begin{cases}4S_n+S_{n-1}-3\text{ if $S_n$ is odd,}\\3S_n-3\text{ if $S_n$ is even.}\end{cases}
$$
This predicts that the next three terms are 30587, 129404, 388209.

Comment: Well done! :-) the equivalent formula for excel is : **(A2-1)*4+1+IF(ISODD(A2),A1,A2*-1)** for *A3* cell

Comment: Nice one, found the $3S_n -3$ thing one minute before you posted the answer. But I didn't assign it to the even property, I just saw that this rule was applied at every 3 calculations.

Comment: Congratulations. How long did it take you -_- took me an hour and a half and apparently it "didn't work"

Answer (score 2):

After about an hour and a half, this is what I came up with;

1, 1, 2, 3, 11, 44, 129, 557, 2354, 7059, 11961, 19233, 66058

I used a difference table to figure it out:

1, 1, 2, 3, 11, 44, 129, 557, 2354, 7059, ?, ?, ?

0, 1, 1, 8, 33, 85, 428, 1797, ?, ?, ?

1, 0, 7, 25, 52, 375, 1369, ?, ?, ?

-1, 7, 18, 27, 323, 994, ?, ?, ?

8, 11, 9, 296, 671, ?, ?, ?

3, -1, 287, 375, ?, ?, ?

-4, 288, 88, ?, ?, ?

292, -200, ?, ?, ?

-492, ?, ?, ?

Start from the bottom, and work your way up, using the difference table;

1, 1, 2, 3, 11, 44, 129, 557, 2354, 7059, 11961, 19233, 66058

0, 1, 1, 8, 33, 85, 428, 1797, 4902, 7272, 46825

1, 0, 7, 25, 52, 375, 1369, 3105, 21370, 39653

-1, 7, 18, 27, 323, 994, 1736, 17265, 18283

8, 11, 9, 296, 671, 742, 889, 1018

3, -1, 287, 375, 171, 167, 129

-4, 288, 88, -204, -4, -296

292, -200, -292, 200, -292

-492, -492, -492, -492

Note: If I did any of the addition/subtraction incorrectly feel free to edit the answer!

Comment: I was afraid all the time writing this safari would crash XD

Comment: That's not true. where did 3 other -492s came from?

Comment: The only solution with your way of thinking is if you find a reasonable pattern between first numbers of each line (i.e. 1,0,1,-1,8,3,-4,292-492) which seems there is no such a pattern. then produce next three first elements and find requested numbers with calculations

Comment: @Rafe The way it worked was it went down till they were all the same, then it continued that pattern of it all being the same. Just look up how to use a difference table to solve a sequence. It may not be the "right" solution you had in mind, but it is technically a correct sequence. If nobody else as a better solution, I'll gladly take best answer.

Comment: This is not a solution. You can use it for every other pattern question. Think about first two 1s. How did they produce 2 and 3? they did not made any the same numbers with your solution. - sorry for not tagging you. idk whats wrong with tag part.

Comment: @Rafe it is still an acceptable sequence of numbers using your original sequence. Just because it isn't the answer you have, don't mean it is wrong. If there is a glass half full of water on the table and you ask me how full/empty it is, and you think it's half empty, but I think it's half full, does that make me wrong

Comment: So there is always a solution using newton's polynomial to these kind of puzzles. I insist that your solution is not an acceptable answer

Comment: "Solution" You simply asked "what is the next 3 numbers" my answer does just that.

Comment: I asked for a reasonable formula. BTW, sorry for wasting your precious time. I'll wait for more answers. No more further comments from me.

Comment: @Rafe I spent a freaking hour and a half working things out, trying to solve YOUR question. I finally figure out 3 actual numbers that fit the sequence, and you say it's wrong!?!? The numbers work out, I can't believe you can say I'm incorrect...

Comment: @Rafe Yeah, this is the problem with sequence puzzle, because there can be infinitely many answers. People proposing these kind of questions should be aware of this and not criticizing different answers, perhaps they can say "This is not the answer that I'm looking for, but thank you for your correct answer!"

Comment: In the list of first differences, you left off the last term $7059-2354=4705$. If you add this in, you have to carry the table one step farther before you get a row with only one term, and if you do I think you'll get the same answer as DumpsterDoofus

Comment: I took the liberty of adding in the omitted term and carrying out the computation (there was also one subtraction error)

Comment: @Rafe this type of question is fundamentally pointless, because *any* answer is defensible with a formula. You're just asking for someone to read your mind.

Comment: (See also the Strong Law of Small Numbers)

Comment: @hobbs, Indeed! I didn't think of that when I was writing replies to warspyking. I was selfish and narrow-minded.

Comment: There are many formulas generating any given finite sequence, but a reasonable answer to the question should be a formula requiring less information than simply listing the given terms

Answer (score 2):

Everyone else's solution is incorrect. The correct solution is to note that the sequence is generated as the values of the following function:

$$f(x)=-\frac{113 x^9}{72576}+\frac{1261 x^8}{20160}-\frac{8917 x^7}{8640}+\frac{4391
   x^6}{480}-\frac{821113 x^5}{17280}+\frac{141589 x^4}{960}-\frac{24088019
   x^3}{90720}+\frac{1269077 x^2}{5040}-\frac{17357 x}{180}+3$$

Plugging in $x=1$ gives 1, ..., and plugging in 10 yields 7059. The first 20 values, are, in  detail:

$$S=\{1,1,2,3,11,44,129,557,2354,7059,13467,6997,-65218,-343550,-1143128,-3097105,-7378745,-1
   6030523,-32434384,-61963825\}$$

Comment: That's a newton polynomial if I'm not mistaken